# Find all pairs of $decianimales$

Tags: number-theory

> An ordered pair $(a, b)$ of positive integers is called  $decianimal$
>   when $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b} $ is equal to a decimal fraction $\dfrac{m}{10}$ with $gcd(m,10)=1$.
>
> Find all pairs $decianimales.$

**Attempt:** Note that $m = \dfrac{10(a+b)}{ab}$ and thus $ab = 10k$. We now have $m = \dfrac{a+b}{k}$. Thus, $\gcd \left (\dfrac{a+b}{k}, 10 \right) = 1$. Then since $ab = 10k$, we can substitute for $a$ to get $\gcd \left (\dfrac{\dfrac{10k}{b}+b}{k},10 \right) = \gcd \left(\dfrac{b^2+10k}{bk},10 \right) = 1$.

I am not sure how to solve the last equation or if it is even possible. Perhaps there is an easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we can get some information by splitting pairs into their common factor and the leftover.

Take any positive integers $a,b$.

Let $d = \gcd(a,b)$.

Then $a = dx$ and $b = dy$ for some positive integers $x,y$ such that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$.

If $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{m}{10}$ for some integer $m$ such that $\gcd(m,10) = 1$:

$\frac{x+y}{dxy} = \frac{m}{10}$.

Note that $\gcd(x+y,x) = \gcd(x+y,y) = 1$.

Let $r = \gcd(x+y,d)$.

Then $x+y = rz$ and $d = rw$ for some positive integers $z,w$ such that $\gcd(z,w) = 1$.

And $\frac{z}{wxy} = \frac{m}{10}$.

Also $\gcd(z,x) = \gcd(z,y) = 1$. [Why?]

Thus $\gcd(z,wxy) = 1$ and hence $z = m$ and $wxy = 10$.

[Now it is easy to list all possible $(w,x,y)$ and check each one. I'll show a random case.]

If $(w,x,y) = (1,2,5)$:

$rz = x+y = 7$.

If $(r,z) = (7,1)$:

$d = rw = 7$.

$(a,b) = (14,35)$.

If $(r,z) = \cdots$:

...

If $(w,x,y) = \cdots$:

...

Comment: Why does $\gcd(z,x) = \gcd(z,y) = 1$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: That's what I'm asking you! I already gave pretty much the solution. If you don't try to figure that out yourself there's nothing left for you.